# Calculate limits of $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sqrt{1+4x}-1}{\ln{(1+3x)}}$

Tags: limits

This is my attempt but I don't know how to continue
$$
\begin{aligned}
L &= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sqrt{1+4x}-1}{\ln{(1+3x)}} \\
&=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(\sqrt{1+4x}-1)(\sqrt{1+4x}-1)}{\ln{(1+3x)}(\sqrt{1+4x}+1)} \\
&=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{4x}{\ln{(1+3x)}(\sqrt{1+4x}+1)}
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need a scaling.

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{4x}{\log(1+3x)} = \frac{4}{3} \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{3x}{\log(1+3x)} = \frac{4}{3} \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{\log(1+x)} = \frac{4}{3}.$$
The rest of the computation is easy.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about this part $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{3x}{\log(1+3x)} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{\log(1+x)}$

Comment: This is done by a change of notation. We can let $y = 3x$. Then, $x \to 0$ is equivalent with $y \to 0$. We can also directly show that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{3x}{\log(1+3x)}  = 1$  in the same manner as in the proof of $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{\log(1+x)}  = 1$.